# ¿Por qué este enlace no me lleva a la url indicada?

Tags: url, botón

En `chrome` me funciona, pero no en `firefox`:

```
<button type="button">
   <a href="http://www.misitio.com">SIGUIENTE</a> 
</button>
```

Cuando pulso en siguiente me lleva a la página que le indico. Esto funciona si uso `chrome`, pero no funciona en `firefox`, que no ejecuta nada.

Comment: pues hacerlo de la siguiente manera para `firefox` `<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><button>Siguiente</button></a>`, lo pongo aquí porque cerraron la pregunta, siendo que es un error común con los estándares de `firefox`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me gustaría que la página se mostrase en la misma ventana, sin abrir una nueva. ¿ Es posible ?. Saludos

Comment: si claro deja te lo pongo como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Este link te lleva a una pagina, sin importar el navegador que uses. 
Saludos.

```html
<a href="https://gett.cl">Llevame a una página interesante</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera sin que se abra en una nueva pagina:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">
  <button>Siguiente</button>
</a>
```

Comment: No acaba de funcionarme. El comando completo que utilizo es:

Comment: que error te marca o porque dices que no te funciona, yo lo he estado probando y funciona bien.